# Read excel file with drop-down lists

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, xlrd

I have an excel file (UK census) with different sheets. The first sheet has some options I can choose from drop-down lists as shown in the pic. The data in the other sheets change based on this selection. I want to read the data from this excel file using Python.

[image: excel file with drop-down list]

The problem is that the data sheets show only part of data related to options I have to choose and if I use Pandas to read this file, it only gives the data related to the options I chose. All the data is there somewhere in the file but not sure how to read that from Pandas or any other Python excel file reading packages.Any help would be appreciated.

You can see the file here:
[UK census excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cy2f7rhb4ixnen2/QUALIFICATIONS.xlsx?dl=0)

Thanks,
dksr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several hidden sheets in the workbook. I assume that the sheets "2001 Data"and "2011 Data" have all the raw data for the respective years.  There are other hidden sheets that do some staging and prep work, but if you want the raw data, you may want to use those two sheets.

Comment: For raw data I am looking at the "2011" and "2001" sheets. But they only show the data (to me and my Python program) for the default option selected in "First Sheet". I want my Python program to see all the data for all the options present in the drop-down lists in "First Sheet". The data is there somewhere in that file but not visible to my Python packages (Pandas for example).

Comment: Please read my answer again. There are hidden sheets with all the data. You will need to unhide them before you can see them.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. In LibreOffice its Sheet -> Show Sheet and it will show hidden sheets.